# Which iPhone bitcoin wallets let you scan a watch only address and sweep addresses?

Tags: wallet, mobile, ios

Currently Mycelium on Android lets you create watch only addresses by scanning the public key QR code and import paper wallet private keys. But the iPhone  iOS version doesn't. What apps are there for iOS that lets you do watch only and import from a paper wallet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are other wallets on iOS but these additionally support xpub import, so you can generate addresses for recieving, without private keys:

- [BitWallet](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/bitwallet-bitcoin-wallet/id777634714)
- [ArcBit](https://itunes.apple.com/ca/app/arcbit-bitcoin-wallet/id999487888)

Answer (score 0):

In case you are looking for an iOS app to *only* watch a bitcoin address (ie. you don't have the private key, or it's on paper or in a hardware wallet), you might be interested in [ocular](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/ocular-btc-address-watch/id1386099675).

Answer (score 0):

Breadwallet can sweep private keys: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WJ7-4Hv5Kq4

AFAIK, there are no iOS wallets that can import private keys.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that [Bitcoin Wallet](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/bitcoin-wallet-by-bitcoin-com/id1252903728) does the job or [coinomi](https://www.coinomi.com/en/)

Answer (score 0):

[Fully Noded iOS](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/fully-noded/id1436425586) is a fantastic option for this I believe. Very powerful mobile iOS wallet for controlling your bitcoin/LN node.